# How to make a graphic loaded via bootstrap css responsive?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

im trying to figure out how to make single graphics which be loaded directly via css responsive.

If i resize the screen, then the graphis get tigter to. But if i have cellphone display, then the graphics going over the fonts. Now i would like to know how i can get the graphics to become smaller that they fit to all sizes.

Im using bootstrap css .

attached you can finde what i mean:

THis is how it looks like normal

http://abload.de/image.php?img=graphic1biy1i.png

And this is how it looks like on small screen

http://abload.de/image.php?img=graphic207zez.png

How can i make the graphics reszising?

---

```
c_cont h1{
background: url("../images/titl_left.png") no-repeat scroll left 9px, url("../images/tit_rght.png") no-repeat scroll right 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);    
color: #d4676b;
font-family: "Miama";
font-size: 37px;
margin:0 auto;
padding: 0px 0;
text-align: center;
width: 63%;
height:auto;
color: #fa6e05;
```

Comment: We're going to need more than just the CSS to fix this issue. Post your HTML structure or make a JSFiddle with a working example of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling it with a width of 63%, so when the screen scales down, it will still be 63%. In general, 63% of a large screen is huge compared to 63% of a mobile phone.

You should utilize a media query to target when you would like your image to scale down.

ie:

```
@media screen max-width (600px){
/*code goes here*/
}
```

Alternatively, you can use something along the lines of max-width and a precentage width, so the banner will always stay in proportion. (This would still require you to use a media query, unless you wanted the banner to take up a large amount of screen in the laptop screen size.

```
c_cont h1{
max-width:600px;
width:100%; /* keeps your image scalable, but will take up 100% of the available width*/
height:auto; /*scales in proportion*/
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried it but it wasn´t working for me. If possible i would send message to one of you with link to show it. i dont want to publish it here.

Comment: I'm in the office now, if you wanna shoot me a message my email is: TylerJStelmach@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

Set the maximum viewport size you would like your settings to apply to using css media queries

```css
    img
    {
        height: 500px;
        width: 700px;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width:640px)
    {
      img
      {
        height: 200px;
        width: 250px;
      }
    }
```

```html
    <img src="https://fanart.tv/api/download.php?type=download&image=13138&section=3" />
```

Run the snippet above in full screen and resize your browser to see the change.